# How to delete all duplicate URLs and keep only the last visitings in Google Chrome History?

Tags: google-chrome, duplicates, browser-history

I want to keep only the last visit of a website in Google Chrome History and delete all duplicate URLs of the websites in the past.

For example, if Google Chrome History shows:

25 July 2018
* mail.google.com
* x.com

24 July 2018
* mail.google.com
* x.com
* y.com

then, I want it to delete duplications and keep only the last visit, as following:
25 July 2018
* mail.google.com
* x.com
24 July 2018
* y.com

Of course, this can be done one-by-one by going Google Chrome History and delete by detecting one-by-one the duplciates. This is a very long way. I want a systematic way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download and install SQLite Browser
2. Close Chrome (because Chrome locks its history database)
3. Open SQLite Browser
4. Press "Open
   Database"
5. Insert "C:\Users[your
   username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" into
   address bar or browse to it. (If you use a profile, choose your
   profile)
6. Choose "All Files" on the bottom right (Chrome does not use
   an extension for its history database so it does not appear by
   default)
7. Open file "History".
8. Click on tab "Execute SQL"

   `DELETE  from visits where id not in (select max(id) from visits v group by v.url)`

Note that it will keep latest unique URLs, wont match any wildcard patterns etc

Answer (score -1):

You can also Shift+Click to select multiple items in history and remove them at once.

Perform a search to bring up the relevant history items
Click the first result
Shift+Click the last result
Click Remove Selected Items